PynputとPyQt6の組み合わせで「illegal hardware instruction」が出る
マウスを自動でクリックするコードを書いていたところ、
zsh: illegal hardware instruction  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3 

というエラーが出ました。
PynputとPyQtの組み合わせの問題ではないかと思い(GUIをつける前は動作していたので)、下記のコード
（ボタンをクリックすると、その後押されたキーがコンソールに表示される）
で試したところ、同じエラーが出ましたので、やはりこの組み合わせが悪いと思われます。
tkinterでも同様の事象が発生するという記事も見ましたので、そもそもGUIとpynputとの組み合わせがそもそも良くないのかもしれませんが、解決方法ご存知の方おられましたらご教授ください。
画面は立ち上がるのですが、ボタンを押すと落ちてエラーを吐きます。
VSCodeのデバッガーは何も言いません。
環境はMac OS Sonoma、Intel Macです。
以下ソースコード全文になります。
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from pynput import keyboard
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("test")

        grid = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(grid)

        self.testbut = QPushButton("テスト")
        self.testbut.clicked.connect(self.function)
        grid.addWidget(self.testbut, 0, 0)
    
    def function(self):
        listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=self.on_press)
        listener.start()

    def on_press(self, key):
        print(key.char)

qAp = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = Window()
mainwindow.show()
qAp.exec()


追記ですが、pythonのバージョンを3.11に下げる、pythonを再インストール、は試しました。

コードを順番に削っていってどのPythonコード行で発生するか、どのライブラリで発生するかを特定するしかないと思います。

ありがとうございます。デバッグメッセージを追加したところ、キーボードリスナーがstart（またはjoin)されるときにエラーが出ているようでした。同様の事例をさらに調べたところ、GUIがユーザーの入力を監視するループと、pynputのリスナーが競合するようです。threadingやmultiprocessingでpynputを別スレッド化してみましたが、エラーが解消しませんでした。解消方法が見つかりましたら投稿します。

【追記】pynputではなく、PyAutoGUIを使い、同様の処理を行うことはできました。
